# Java Iterate Bits in Byte Array

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bit, loops

How can i iterate bits in a byte array?

Comment: You can't. At least not directly. What are you trying to do, perhaps there is a better way. A byte array holds a collection of bytes.

Comment: And once again, I wish that java.util.BitSet had a byte[] constructor.

Comment: It can be done.  I'd vote you go with Jon Skeet's method.  However, in most cases when working with bits, there are some fancy bitwise operators that can make your task go much faster.  If you tell us what you're trying to do, exactly, we might help you find a better way than iterating the bits.

Comment: I am trying to interpret the bitfield message of bittorrent protocol each bit represents a a piece's availability. i need to iterate and determine which peer has which pieces available.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You'd have to write your own implementation of `Iterable<Boolean>` which took an array of bytes, and then created `Iterator<Boolean>` values which remembered the current index into the byte array *and* the current index within the current byte. Then a utility method like this would come in handy:

```
private static Boolean isBitSet(byte b, int bit)
{
    return (b & (1 << bit)) != 0;
}
```

(where `bit` ranges from 0 to 7). Each time `next()` was called you'd have to increment your bit index within the current byte, and increment the byte index within byte array if you reached "the 9th bit".

It's not really *hard* - but a bit of a pain. Let me know if you'd like a sample implementation...

Answer (score 18):

```
public class ByteArrayBitIterable implements Iterable<Boolean> {
    private final byte[] array;

    public ByteArrayBitIterable(byte[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public Iterator<Boolean> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Boolean>() {
            private int bitIndex = 0;
            private int arrayIndex = 0;

            public boolean hasNext() {
                return (arrayIndex < array.length) && (bitIndex < 8);
            }

            public Boolean next() {
                Boolean val = (array[arrayIndex] >> (7 - bitIndex) & 1) == 1;
                bitIndex++;
                if (bitIndex == 8) {
                    bitIndex = 0;
                    arrayIndex++;
                }
                return val;
            }

            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        ByteArrayBitIterable test = new ByteArrayBitIterable(
                   new byte[]{(byte)0xAA, (byte)0xAA});
        for (boolean b : test)
            System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Original:

```
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
{
   byte b = byteArray[i];
   byte mask = 0x01;
   for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
   {
      bool value = b & mask;
      mask << 1;
   }
}
```

Or using Java idioms

```
for (byte b : byteArray ) {
  for ( int mask = 0x01; mask != 0x100; mask <<= 1 ) {
      boolean value = ( b & mask ) != 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd say C# if I had to guess.

Comment: @Oscar: That's a left-shift operator. Java has it too.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use a BitInputStream like the one you can find [here](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Bit_Input/Output_Stream_utility_classes_for_efficient_data_transfer) and write code like this:

```
BitInputStream bin = new BitInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    while(true){
        int bit = bin.readBit();
        // do something
    }
bin.close();
```

(Note: Code doesn't contain EOFException or IOException handling for brevity.)

But I'd go with Jon Skeets variant and do it on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I needed some bit streaming in my application. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/open-ig/source/browse/trunk/open-ig/src/hu/openig/utils/IOUtils.java) you can find my BitArray implementation. It is not a real iterator pattern but you can ask for 1-32 bits from the array in a streaming way. There is also an alternate implementation called BitReader later in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I know, probably not the "coolest" way to do it, but you can extract each bit with the following code.

```
    int n = 156;

String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
System.out.println(bin);

char arr[] = bin.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println("Bit number " + (i + 1) + " = " + arr[i]);
}
```

10011100

Bit number 1 = 1

Bit number 2 = 0

Bit number 3 = 0

Bit number 4 = 1

Bit number 5 = 1

Bit number 6 = 1

Bit number 7 = 0

Bit number 8 = 0

Comment: It's cool because it makes no use of those "scary" bitwise operations.

Comment: I don't see any need to use the bitwise operator for something as simple as the OP asked for: iterate through the bits.

Comment: This would answer the question better if it showed how to extract bits from a *byte array* (instead of String or char array)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the byte array, and for each byte use the bitwise operators to iterate though its bits.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html) for this:

```java
byte[] bytes=...;
BitSet bitSet=BitSet.valueOf(bytes);
for(int i=0;i<bitSet.length();i++){
    boolean bit=bitSet.get(i);
    //use your bit
}
```