# Convert a byte into a boolean array of length 4 in Java

Tags: java, byte, bit

I need to convert a byte into an array of 4 booleans in Java. How might I go about this?

Comment: How do you imagine this conversion taking place?  A byte contains eight bits.  Do you want to use four and throw away four?

Comment: There are eight bits in one byte. Therefore you can't do this unless the byte value is guaranteed to be less than b1111. Is this a fair assumption to make?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034473/java-iterate-bits-in-byte-array/1034501#1034501  An answer that gives you nearly everything you're after, if you know what bits you're interested in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per Michael Petrotta's comment to your question, you need to decide which bits in the 8-bit byte should be tested for the resulting boolean array.  For demonstration purposes, let's assume you want the four rightmost bits, then something like this should work:

```
public static boolean[] booleanArrayFromByte(byte x) {
    boolean bs[] = new boolean[4];
    bs[0] = ((x & 0x01) != 0);
    bs[1] = ((x & 0x02) != 0);
    bs[2] = ((x & 0x04) != 0);
    bs[3] = ((x & 0x08) != 0);
    return bs;
}
```

The hexadecimal values (`0x01`, `0x02`, etc.) in this example are special bit masks that have only a single bit set at the desired location; so 0x01 has only the rightmost bit set, 0x08 has only the fourth-from-right bit set.  By testing the given byte against these values with the bitwise AND operator (`&`) you will get that value back if the bit is set, or zero if not.  If you want to check different bits, other than the rightmost four, then you'll have to create different bitmasks.

Answer (score 6):

#### On specification

Others are raising a *very valid* point: in Java, [`Byte.SIZE == 8`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Byte.SIZE). That is, there are 8 bits in a `byte`. You need to define how you want to map 8 bits into 4 `boolean` values; otherwise we can only guess what is it you're trying to do.

---

#### On `BitSet`

Regardless of how you do this mapping, however, it's unlikely that `boolean[]` really is the best representation. A [`java.util.BitSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) may be better. Here's an example:

```
import java.util.*;
public class BitSetExample {
    static BitSet toBitSet(byte b) {
        BitSet bs = new BitSet(Byte.SIZE);
        for (int i = 0; i < Byte.SIZE; i++) {
            if (((b >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                bs.set(i);
            }
        }
        return bs;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BitSet bs = toBitSet((byte) 10);
        System.out.println(bs); // prints "{1, 3}"
        System.out.println(bs.get(3)); // prints "true"
        System.out.println(bs.get(2)); // prints "false"

        byte b = 25;
        System.out.println(toBitSet(b)); // prints "{0, 3, 4}"

        bs.or(toBitSet(b));
        System.out.println(bs); // prints "{0, 1, 3, 4}"
    }
}
```

The above code uses the standard bit probing technique to convert a `byte` to a `BitSet`. Note that a `(byte) 10` has its bits 1 and 3 set (i.e. `10 = 2^1 + 2^3` where `^` denotes exponentiation).

The example also shows how to perform an `or`/set union operation on `BitSet`.

---

#### On `EnumSet`

Possibly another applicable data structure is an [`EnumSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/EnumSet.html), which is a [`Set`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) implementation highly optimized for `enum`. Here's an example:

```
import java.util.*;
public class EnumSetExample {
    enum Style {
        BOLD, ITALIC, UNDERLINE, BLINKING;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnumSet<Style> myStyle = EnumSet.of(Style.BOLD, Style.UNDERLINE);

        System.out.println(myStyle);
        // prints "[BOLD, UNDERLINE]"

        System.out.println(myStyle.contains(Style.UNDERLINE));
        // prints "true"
        System.out.println(myStyle.contains(Style.BLINKING));
        // prints "false" (thank goodness!)

        myStyle.add(Style.ITALIC);
        System.out.println(myStyle);
        // prints "[BOLD, ITALIC, UNDERLINE]"
    }
}
```

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 32: Use `EnumSet` instead of bit fields*

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to maerics' answer, this is how you could convert the bool array back into a byte, if needed :

```c#
public static byte byteFromBooleanArray(bool[] _boolArray)
    {
        byte x = 0;
        x += _boolArray[0] ? (byte)1 : (byte)0;
        x += _boolArray[1] ? (byte)2 : (byte)0;
        x += _boolArray[2] ? (byte)4 : (byte)0;
        x += _boolArray[3] ? (byte)8 : (byte)0;

        return x;
    }
```