# How can I convert a number to an array of Booleans in java?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, byte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a byte into a boolean array of length 4 in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058157/convert-a-byte-into-a-boolean-array-of-length-4-in-java)

I am currently studying java, and making games.
I have come on the situation with I need to make some **test-data** for a game.

I work with tiles in a 2D-array(a map of the game), and each tile needs **four bool-values**.
So instead of writing the tile in true or false, I want to use a simple **Byte**, **written** in **binary**.

Example: **"0b0110"** instead of **"false, true, true, false"**

So I need a way to **convert** my **binary**-written Bytes to **arrays** of **Boolean**.

Comment: Try to find out how to extract individual bits from a a byte

Comment: Why convert these to `boolean[]`, instead of just manipulating the bits directly on the `byte`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
byte b = 0b0110;
boolean [] flags = new boolean[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    flags[i] = (b & (1 << i)) != 0;
}
```

Going the other way:

```
boolean [] flags = {false, true, true, false};
byte b = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    if (flags[i]) b |= (1 << i);
}
```

I would recommend using `byte` and `boolean` primitives unless you need to box them as `Byte` and `Boolean` for some other reason.

Comment: The Keymaker of Stackoverflow +(10^10)

Answer (score 0):

#### boolean to byte

For converting one `boolean` variable to one `byte` variable :

```
boolean vIn = true;
byte vOut = (byte) (vIn ? 1 : 0);
```

For converting array of `boolean` to array of `bytes`:

```
        boolean[] allBooleans = new boolean[3];
        allBooleans[0] = true;
        allBooleans[1] = false;
        allBooleans[2] = true;
        byte allByte[] = new byte[allBooleans.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < allBooleans.length; i++) {
            allByte[i] = (byte) (allBooleans[i] ? 1 : 0);
        }
```

#### byte to boolean

For converting one `byte` variable to one `boolean` variable

```
byte vIn = 1;
boolean vOut = vIn != 0;
```

For converting array of `bytes` to array of `booleans`

```
    byte[] allBytes = new byte[3];
    allBytes[0] = new Byte("1");
    allBytes[1] = new Byte("0");
    allBytes[2] = new Byte("1");
    boolean allBoolean[] = new boolean[allBytes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < allBytes.length; i++) {
        allBoolean[i] = allBytes[i] != 0;
    }
```