# How can I create a stream of bits from a byte array?

Tags: java, byte, bit

I have a byte array and I need a stream of bits. I've figured out that this is not completely straight forward. I'll be using a while loop and doing something to every bit.

(Pseudo of what I think I need)

```
bytes[] byteArray = //somecode
BitStream bitstream = new BitStream(byteArray);

while (bitstream.hasNext) { //or bitstream.read != -1
//do something with bit
}
```

**EDIT:** By the way, as far as I know, BitStream is not actually a class, but just to show what I think I need.

Comment: So you basically want to iterate over all bits of an array? Is [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html) sufficient for your purpose?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1034888/5898421 is what you're looking for